# Orange Feature Construction widget: Inability to see formulas while file sharing

Tags: orange, feature-construction

Our team is sharing Orange "work bench" files across team members. Unfortunately, we find the Feature Construction widget does not display code consistently (nor is there any "x" to indicate an error).
1. In 2 versions of 3.4.1, we could share the Feature Construction widget
2. However, Feature nodes created in version 3.4.1 could not be viewed in 3.13 or the standalone Orange.
An image of the original coder's screen - followed by the recipient's screen - is shown. How do we package the program appropriately to share across users who may have multiple versions of Orange? 
Generally, do you recommend that data manipulation like feature engineering be done in Python instead of this widget?
Thanks, Layne

[image]